# Can't get this simple HTML email form working

Tags: html, forms, email

I'm just trying to make a simple email form, but for some reason when I type click submit, nothing happens. I just want it to open up outlook or the email window. Any suggestions as to what I'm doing wrong?

```
    <form action="mailto:GeneFdez@gmail.com" method="post" id="contactform" class="contact-form">                  

                                        <div class="row form-group">

                                            <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 form-group" id="contact-name">
                                                <i class="fa fa-user icon-contact"></i>
                                                <input type="text" name="name" class="form-control name-contact" style="margin-top: 0;" placeholder="Name..." />
                                            </div>          

                                            <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 form-group" id="contact-email">
                                                <i class="fa fa-envelope icon-contact"></i>
                                                <input type="text" name="email" class="form-control email-contact" placeholder="Email..." />
                                            </div>  

                                            <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 form-group" id="contact-subject">
                                                <i class="fa fa-question icon-contact"></i>
                                                <input type="text" name="subject" class="form-control subject-contact" placeholder="Subject..." />
                                            </div>  

                                            <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 form-group" id="contact-message">
                                                <i class="fa fa-comments icon-contact"></i>
                                                <textarea name="message" cols="90" rows="10" class="form-control message-contact" id="inputError" placeholder="Message..."></textarea>
                                            </div> 

                                            <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 form-group" style="margin-bottom: 0;">
                                                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-block btn-cta btn-cta-contact-2">Send<i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i></button>
                                            </div>   

                                        </div><!--//row-->

                                    </form><!--//contact-form-->
```

Comment: does work for me.

Comment: Example  page is here: http://boomboomdesigns.com/gene/
Under the contact section

Answer (score 0):

To run the mail function, you need to host the code online ... In localhost, it doesn't work as there is no active server to connect.

Comment: I have it hosted here: boomboomdesigns.com/gene under the contact section